# What is considered a large (medium, small) input for simple feedforward neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

What would be considered a large (or medium or small) number of input neurons for a feedforward neural network?

While I am trying to do phoneme detection using inputs of 3200 sound-samples, I became curious how to categorize input sizes of a simple 3 layered ANN (input - hidden - output).

Comment: Why does it matter?  You don't really have control over the size of your input layer.  It will always have the same size as the number of your features.

Comment: I was just curious what the biggest feed forward nets were that have been successfully trained. And yes, I do have control in that I can decide the size of the inputs to a certain degree.